# How to Create a Git repository using github-cli?

Tags: git, github, github-cli

How do you create a GitHub repository using [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli) (vs having to go to github.com and creating a github repo from their GUI)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Create+repository+Command+Line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GitHub just released their CLI (command line interface), so now you can create GitHub repos from command line / terminal.

**Step 1:**

Download the client for your system [here](https://cli.github.com/)

**Step 2:**

Once it's installed, run `gh auth login` in your command prompt and follow the instructions to log in.

**Step 3:**

After you're logged in, in your command prompt go to a directory where you want to create the repository, run `git init` in the project directory to initialize it.

Then run the command `gh repo create` and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

To create a new repo in the current directory, run this command:

```sh
gh repo create myRepo
```

Here is an example of a more complex configuration:

```sh
gh repo create myAwesomeRepo --public -d 'my description' --enable-issues=false
```

To see more options when creating a repo, you can always ask for help:

```sh
gh repo create --help
```